# How to create a curved content area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make the content area of the webpage alone to look like a curved TV display. Something like this:

[image]

The webpage doesn't have to be responsive but i should be able to zoom-in and zoom-out the curve area using the mouse and should be able to slide the curve. Looking for suitable frameworks/scripts that could help me do this.

Comment: try Effect 5 from this [link](https://paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects) for curve view

Comment: @Dhaval Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a curved content illusion you split it in rectangules.

Example source : http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/creating-3d-worlds-with-html-and-css/

[image]

Demo : http://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/ksayr

An example on how to do css transformations with iframe:

```css
       #transformation {
        -webkit-perspective: 800;
        perspective: 800;
        margin: 100px 0 100px 50px;
      }
       #transformation iframe {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 60deg);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
        transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 60deg);
      }
       #transformation iframe:hover {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 65deg);
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 65deg);
      }
       #transformation {
        -webkit-perspective: 800;
        perspective: 800;
        margin: 100px 0 100px 50px;
      }
      #transformation iframe {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 50deg);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
        transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 50deg);
      }
      #transformation iframe:hover {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 50deg);
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 55deg);
      }
       #transformation {
        -webkit-perspective: 800;
        perspective: 800;
        margin: 100px 0 100px 50px;
      }
       #transformation iframe {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 60deg);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
        transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 60deg);
      }
       #transformation iframe:hover {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 65deg);
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 65deg);
      }
       #transformation {
        -webkit-perspective: 800;
        perspective: 800;
        margin: 100px 0 100px 50px;
      }
       #transformation iframe {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 750deg);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
        transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 75deg);
      }
       #transformation iframe:hover {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 80deg);
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 450deg);
      }
       #transformation {
        -webkit-perspective: 800;
        perspective: 800;
        margin: 100px 0 100px 50px;
      }
       #transformation iframe {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 50deg);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
        transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 50deg);
      }
       #transformation iframe:hover {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 550deg);
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 55deg);
      }
       #transformation {
        -webkit-perspective: 800;
        perspective: 800;
        margin: 100px 0 100px 50px;
      }
       #transformation iframe {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 60deg);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
        transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 1, 60deg);
      }
       #transformation iframe:hover {
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 650deg);
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 65deg);
      }
```

```html
    <div id="transformation">
      <iframe src = "http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/" height= 300px width= 400px /iframe>
    </div>
```

Finally, you can use html5 to create a grid surface. You can render iframe on the grid elements and listen to events you find useful, like zoom (multitouch or scrollbar). Building such surface and managing its events can be done with a javascript library called jQuery.

I hope you found this answer useful.

Comment: This is wonderful but it all is greek and latin to me, is there a simple example that you can show which looks like a curved wall with zoom and zoom out?

Comment: A barrel in (http://keithclark.co.uk/labs/css-fps/desktop/) is your sample - you zoom in by going forward and zoom out by going backward. The reason why it is greek to you is that this task difficulty is difficult. Assuming you can solve easy and moderate difficulty tasks, but struggle with advanced problems then consider that difficult task forces you to solve several advanced level problems (requiring a lot of preknowledge). I assume that for senior level software engineer this task would take about 2-4 hours and for architect 30-45m (with tests).

Comment: I hope this answers your question. If you have a problem implementing it, you can ask another a question showing what you have tried and what does not work as you would expect. My one warning is that do not expect everything to be easy, for an entry level software engineer archiving to solve all the subproblems from end-to-end would take around ~2 weeks (assuming he really tries). If you start skipping problems you just do not get better.

Comment: Thanks a lot @margus

Answer (score -2):

you can do this with adding border-radius in css.

```
<textarea style="border-radius: 30px;" rows="3"></textarea>
```

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/
look through this article for more info

Comment: are you need a curved image viewer??

Comment: I require the content area of a web page to look like a curved one, sorry if my question isn't clear. The curved area should look like something as shown in the image. Also the curved area should be zoomable, something like this : http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_periodictable Not looking for a curved image viewer.